# Select one week out of a monthly calendar

Tags: website-design, calendar

So I have a monthly calendar on the upper side of my page. Users are able to select on a specific day inside this calendar and a the bottom part will dynamically list events occurring at that day.

I want the user to be able to select a whole week (Sunday .. Saturday) all together, and the bottom part will list all events occurring in that week.

My question is how can I make the user select a whole week through my monthly calendar? I need it to be intuitive as much as possible.

Comment: click to the left of that week. To make this more intuitive/affordable, you could display weeknumbers or some "grabber" type graphic for each week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to have a Week column on the side of your date picker, clicking the week's number would highlight the whole row of dates for that week the same way selecting the day (presumably) highlights the selected item:

[image: mockup]

If you don't have enough room to spell out Week on the week column you might want to have a tooltip on hover to give a bit of explanation for discovery.

Comment: I would like to do it as well. Is there a javascript / jQuery ...etc elemnt that can do it?